# HttpRequest Upload file sharepoint / msgraph - filezsize is changed

Tags: api, sharepoint, upload, httprequest

I use a program with a sort of Low code / no code.

I am trying to upload files  to a drive on sharepoint.

It works ok for text files but for other files the filesize is changed (its get bigger) so the output of the file is corrupted.

This is the output send with HttpRequest.
and the file in binary but when i look at the uploaded file some characters are changed

i tried doing the samen with postman and that work perfect.

---

### Request:
PUT /v1.0/drives/b!L5AG0eQjxkWwOposXiY5MRonKsPCmNNMiU6QQYD0ZfzyKwqI0-DMRYT5YVHXgRIK/items/root:/0.pdf:/content HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Authorization: Bearer : here shows its the Acces_token
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 45156
Expect: 100-continue

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of solution

when the file is uploaded i convert it to Base64
Then i upload it to sharepoint (file can't be opend on sharepoint)

i have created a flow with power automate that converts every added file in sharepoint @Base64Tobinary - after the flow is completed i can open the file in sharepoint.

But this only works with small files (less 5 mb).